# annihilated coefficient extractor (ACE)

Tags: generating-functions

Please, someone can explain me how works the annihilated coefficient extractor
technique (ACE). I have seen some examples but i can't understand.
Is there some text to read about this specific argument?

Thank in advance.

Comment: Where did you hear about it? Could you reference the source?

Answer (score 2):

We start with some general information:

- The *coefficient of* operator is thoroughly described in *[Bracket notation for the ‘coefficient of’ operator](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9402216.pdf)* by  D.E. Knuth.
- There are instructive examples in section 5.4 *Generating Functions* in *[Concrete Mathematics](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/%7Er97002/temp/Concrete%20Mathematics%202e.pdf)* by R.L. Graham, D.E. Knuth and O. Patashnik.
- A lot of nice material can be found in *[Generatingfunctionology](https://www.math.upenn.edu/%7Ewilf/gfology2.pdf)* by H.S. Wilf which is a great starter for problems of this kind.

> The ACE also called *substitution rule* is demonstrated in the example below. The key is the representation mentioned in (3).
> We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{j=0}^k}&\color{blue}{\binom{j+r-1}{j}\binom{k-j+s-1}{k-j}}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{-r}{j}(-1)^j\binom{-s}{k-j}(-1)^{k-j}\\
> &=(-1)^k\sum_{j=0}^\infty[z^j](1+z)^{-r}[u^{k-j}](1+u)^{-s}\tag{1}\\
> &=(-1)^k[u^k](1+u)^{-s}\sum_{j=0}^\infty u^j[z^j](1+z)^{-r}\tag{2}\\
> &=(-1)^k[u^k](1+u)^{-s}(1+u)^{-r}\tag{3}\\
> &=(-1)^k[u^k](1+u)^{-r-s}\\
> &=(-1)^k\binom{-r-s}{k}\\
> &\color{blue}{=\binom{k+r+s-1}{k}}
> \end{align*}
> and the *[Chu-Vandermonde identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity#Chu.E2.80.93Vandermonde_identity)* follows.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we apply the *coefficient of* operator twice and set the upper limit of the series to $\infty$ without changing anything since we are adding zeros only.
- In (2) we use the linearity of the *coefficient of* operator and apply the rule $[z^{p}]z^qA(z)=[z^{p-q}]A(z)$.
- In (3) we apply the substitution rule of the *coefficient of* operator with $u=z$
  \begin{align*}
  A(u)=\sum_{j=0}^\infty a_j u^j=\sum_{j=0}^\infty u^j [z^j]A(z)
  \end{align*}

> Here are some more examples using the substitution rule:
>
> - *[Ex. 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2520717/is-there-an-explicit-expression-for-sum-j-k12nj-choose-kn-choose-j-n/2527532#2527532)*: Is there an explicit expression for $\sum_{j= k+1}^{2n}{j\choose k}{n\choose j-n}$?.
> - *[Ex. 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1795155/a-strange-combinatorial-identity-sum-limits-j-1k-1k-jjk-binomkj/1796393#1796393)*: A strange combinatorial identity: $\sum\limits_{j=1}^k(-1)^{k-j}j^k\binom{k}{j}=k!$.
> - *[Ex. 3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/822466/sum-involving-bernoulli-numbers-sum-r-1n-binom2n2r-1-fracb-2rr/888651#888651)*: Sum Involving Bernoulli Numbers : $\sum_{r=1}^n \binom{2n}{2r-1}\frac{B_{2r}}{r}=\frac{2n-1}{2n+1}$ by Marko Riedel

**Note:** The substitution rule stated as formula 1.6 and a lot of other powerful techniques were introduced by *G.P. Egorychev* in [Integral Representation and the Computation of Combinatorial Sums](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0821845128).

Comment: @MarkoRiedel: Thanks, Marko. I've added your answer.

Comment: @MarkoRiedel: If it is ok for you I would like  to keep the reference in my answer since it is more visible there.

Comment: (+1). Very useful bibliography. There are some more examples of the *substitution rule* being referenced by *ACE* at the following [MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/371011/).

Comment: Apologies if I missed it but I am particularly searching for a reference in which the method of deriving the Stirling number representation of the sum of integers was shown.

Comment: @Buraian: See e.g. section 4 in *[this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1510.05402.pdf)*. You might also want to search the net with keywords "Faulhaber formula, Stirling second kind".