# Why is this result using binomial coefficients true?

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, combinations, binomial-theorem

I was doing a set of problems for IITJEE and one of the sentences in a solution to a question given says that 
$$
\binom{n}{0} + \frac{1}{2}\left[\binom{n}{0}-\binom{n}{1}\right] + \frac{1}{3}\left[\binom{n}{0}-\binom{n}{1}+\binom{n}{2}\right]+\cdots\\
=\binom{n-1}{0} + \frac{1}{2}\binom{n-1}{1}(-1)^1 + \frac{1}{3}\binom{n-1}{2}(-1)^2+\cdots
$$ 
In the solution it is given to consider $(1-x)^n$ multiplied by $(1-x)^{-1}$. 
Now I know that $(1-x)^n =\binom{n}{0} -\binom{n}{1}x + \binom{n}{2}x^2+\cdots$ and $(1-x)^{-1} = 1 - x + x^2-\cdots$ , but implementing these I am not getting a result. Is there anything I have missed, and am I going in the correct way? What should I do?

Comment: Hint: try to expand the LHS

Comment: Are Ci and C(n-1 i)  the same?

Comment: @NewGuy by expand would you please tell me which identity to use?

Comment: You still have a chance to edit your question bringing it into a readable form.

Comment: Please check if I have edited your question correctly.

Comment: Yes you have, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use the generalized hockey-stick identity
$$
\sum_{i=0}^k\binom{m+i}{i}=\binom{m+k+1}{k}\quad(m\in\mathbb{C})\tag{H.S.}
$$
which follows from the regular hockey-stick identity via the polynomial method to prove that
$$
\sum_{i=0}^k(-1)^{i}\binom{n}{i}
=(-1)^k\binom{n-1}{k}.$$
Indeed, since $(-1)^{i}\binom{n}{i}=(-1)^{i}(n)_{i}/i!=(-n)^{(i)}/i!=\binom{i-n-1}{i}$ (where $(n)_i$ is  the falling factorial and $n^{(i)}$ is the rising factorial), we have that
$$
\sum_{i=0}^k(-1)^{i}\binom{n}{i}=\sum_{i=0}^k\binom{i-n-1}{i}\stackrel{\text{H.S.}}{=}\binom{k-n}{k}=(-1)^k\binom{n-1}{k}
$$
as desired.

Answer (score 4):

Here is answer where we follow the advice in the solution and use $(1-x)^n$ and $\frac{1}{1-x}$, but *inside out*. It is convenient to use the *coefficient of* operator $[x^k]$ to denote the coefficient of $x^k$ in a series. This way we can write for instance
\begin{align*}
[x^k](1+x)^n=\binom{n}{k}\tag{1}
\end{align*}

> We obtain for non-negative integers $n,k$:
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{n}{j}(-1)^j}&=\sum_{j=0}^k[x^j](1-x)^n\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^{k}[x^{k-j}](1-x)^n\tag{3}\\
> &=[x^k](1-x)^n\sum_{j=0}^kx^j\tag{4}\\
> &=[x^k](1-x)^n\frac{1-x^{k+1}}{1-x}\tag{5}\\
> &=[x^k](1-x)^{n-1}\tag{6}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=(-1)^k\binom{n-1}{k}}\tag{7}
> \end{align*}
>   and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (2) we use the *coefficient of* operator according to (1).
- In (3) we change the order of summation for convenience by letting $j\to k-j$.
- In (4) we use the linearity of the *coefficient of* operator and apply the rule $[x^{p-q}]A(x)=[x^p]x^qA(x)$.
- In (5) we apply the *[finite geometric series formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula)*.
- In (6) we note that the term $x^{k+1}$ do not contribute to $[x^k]$ and we can simplify accordingly.
- In (7) we select the coefficient of $x^k$.

*Hint:* Note that $\frac{1}{1-x}=1+x+x^2+\cdots$.

Comment: Thank you! Is there some name for the rule [xp−q]A(x)=[xp]xqA(x).? Is there some more information about it? And why does x^k+1 not contribute to [x^k]?

Comment: @Hema: You're welcome. This rule is called *shifting*. See *[this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2635408/annihilated-coefficient-extractor-ace/2636184#2636184)* for references and see *[this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2384932/a-nice-but-somewhat-challenging-binomial-identity/2394634#2394634)* for a somewhat more challenging application.

Comment: @Hema: $\frac{x^{k+1}}{1−x}=x^{k+1}(1+x+x^2+⋯)= x^{k+1}+x^{k+2}+x^{k+3}+\cdots$ and since we are looking for $[x^k]A(x)$ which means the coefficient of $x^k$ which is zero in the expansion above, there is no contribution.

Comment: @FelixMarin: Many thanks for the hint. Corrected, and thanks for the credit. :-)

Answer (score 2):

For the proof it suffices to show that
$$
\sum_{i=0}^k (-1)^i\binom{n}{i}=(-1)^k\binom{n-1}{k}.
$$

The simplest way to demonstrate this is by induction. The statement is obviously true for $k=0$. Assumption that it is true for $k$ implies that it is true for $k+1$ as well:
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{k+1} (-1)^i\binom{n}{i}=\sum_{i=0}^{k} (-1)^i\binom{n}{i}+
(-1)^{k+1}\binom{n}{k+1}\stackrel{I.H.}{=}(-1)^k\binom{n-1}{k}+(-1)^{k+1}\binom{n}{k+1}\\
=(-1)^{k+1}\left[\binom{n}{k+1}-\binom{n-1}{k}\right]=(-1)^{k+1}\binom{n-1}{k+1}.
$$