# Understanding and verifying the formula for $\binom{T}{B}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions, generating-functions

I am studying a formula that I came across in my research, which is given by:

$$\binom{T}{B}= \frac{1}{T-B}\sum_{\ell=1}^{\infty} \binom{T + \ell - 1}{B - 1} \left(1 - \frac{B}{T} \right)^\ell \cdot \ell$$

I have checked this equation numerically and found it to be accurate, and I want to clarify that the right-hand side of this formula is not an expectation with respect to $\ell$, but I am having difficulty understanding its meaning and how it was derived.

I have tried searching for possible generating functions or discrete probability distributions that might be related to this formula, but so far, I have not been successful.

Any help or clarification would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: So just to be sure:  It seems you are *not* interested in interpreting the right-hand side as the mean of a negative binomial variable.  If that's correct, can you offer any context? -- e.g., where this formula comes from?

Comment: My apologies, I sketched out my idea a bit too quickly earlier.  I had been thinking we could rewrite that $\binom{T+\ell+1}{B-1}$ as $\alpha \binom{B+\ell-1}{B-1}$, where $\alpha$ did not depend on $\ell$.  I had gotten something, but I see now that I made a mistake.  (A bit more careful thought now suggests why that wouldn't be possible anyway.)  At this point, I'd understand if you were a bit skeptical :) but the only other idea I have:  It looks as though you might be able to interpret the sum as a hypergeometric function?

Comment: Right, I'm fairly certain we have $\sum_{\ell\ge 1} \binom{T+\ell-1}{B-1} \; \ell \; z^\ell = z \binom{T}{B-1} F_{2,1} (T+1, 2; T-B+2; z)$.  But I'm not sure that's helpful :/.

Comment: @dmk Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a two-step approach. At first we transform the identity into an equivalent one which contains a finite sum only. We use the *coefficient of* operator $[z^n]$ to denote the coefficient of $z^n$ of a series. This way we can write for instance
\begin{align*}
[z^k](1+z)^n=\binom{n}{k}\tag{1}
\end{align*}

Since
\begin{align*}
\binom{T}{B}=\binom{T}{T-B}=\frac{T}{T-B}\binom{T-1}{T-B-1}=\frac{T}{T-B}\binom{T-1}{B}
\end{align*}
we want to show
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{T\binom{T-1}{B}=\sum_{l=1}^{\infty}\binom{T+l-1}{B-1}\left(1-\frac{B}{T}\right)^ll}\tag{2}
\end{align*}

Putting $\alpha:=1-\frac{B}{T}$ the right-hand side of (2) can be written as>

> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{l=1}^{\infty}}&\color{blue}{\binom{T+l-1}{B-1}\alpha^ll}\\
> &=\sum_{l=1}^{\infty}[z^{B-1}](1+z)^{T+l-1}\alpha^ll\tag{4.1}\\
> &=[z^{B-1}](1+z)^{T-1}\sum_{l=1}^{\infty}l\alpha^l(1+z)^l\\
> &=[z^{B-1}](1+z)^{T}\frac{d}{dz}\sum_{l=1}^{\infty}\alpha^l(1+z)^l\\
> &=[z^{B-1}](1+z)^T\frac{d}{dz}\left(\frac{1}{1-\alpha(1+z)}-1\right)\\
> &=[z^{B-1}]\frac{\alpha(1+z)^T}{\left(1-\alpha(1+z)\right)^2}\\
> &=[z^{B-1}]\frac{\alpha(1+z)^T}{(1-\alpha)^2\left(1-\frac{\alpha z}{1-\alpha}\right)^2}\\
> &=\frac{\alpha}{(1-\alpha)^2}[z^{B-1}](1+z)^T
> \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\binom{-2}{j}\left(-\frac{\alpha z}{1-\alpha}\right)^j\tag{4.2}\\
> &=\frac{\alpha}{(1-\alpha)^2}[z^{B-1}]
> \sum_{i=0}^T\binom{T}{i}z^i\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}(j+1)\left(\frac{\alpha z}{1-\alpha}\right)^j\tag{4.3}\\
> &=\frac{\alpha}{(1-\alpha)^2}[z^{B-1}]
> \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{j=0}^n(j+1)\left(\frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha}\right)^j\binom{T}{n-j}z^n\tag{4.4}\\
> &=\frac{\alpha}{(1-\alpha)^2}\sum_{j=0}^{B-1}\binom{T}{B-1-j}(j+1)\left(\frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha}\right)^j\tag{4.5}\\
> &=\frac{1}{1-\alpha}\sum_{j=0}^{B-1}\binom{T}{B-(j+1)}(j+1)\left(\frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha}\right)^{j+1}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{1-\alpha}\sum_{j=1}^{B}\binom{T}{B-j}j\left(\frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha}\right)^j}\tag{4.6}\\
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (4.1) we use the *coefficient of* operator according to (1).
- In (4.2) we use the *[binomial series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)*.
- In (4.3) we use the binomial identity $\binom{-p}{q}=\binom{p+q-1}{q}(-1)^q$.
- In (4.4) we multiply out the series.
- In (4.5) we select the coefficient of $z^{B-1}$.
- In (4.6) we shift the index $j$ by 1 and start with $j=1$.

> Since $\frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha}=\frac{T}{B}\left(1-\frac{B}{T}\right)=\frac{T}{B}-1$, we obtain from (4.6) the following finite sum identity equivalent with (2):
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{B\binom{T-1}{B}=\sum_{j=0}^B\binom{T}{B-j}j\left(\frac{T}{B}-1\right)^j}\tag{5}
> \end{align*}

Now in a second step we can considerably simplify the right-hand sum of (5). Putting $z:=\frac{T}{B}-1$ we obtain

> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{j=0}^B}&\color{blue}{\binom{T}{B-j}jz^j}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^B\binom{T}{j}(B-j)z^{B-j}\tag{6.1}\\
> &=B\sum_{j=0}^B\binom{T}{j}z^{B_j}-\sum_{j=1}^B\binom{T}{j}jz^{B-j}\\
> &=B\sum_{j=0}^B\binom{T}{j}z^{B-j}-T\sum_{j=1}^B\binom{T-1}{j-1}z^{B-j}\tag{6.2}\\
> &=B\left(\sum_{j=0}^B\binom{T-1}{j}z^{B-j}+\sum_{j=1}^B\binom{T-1}{j-1}z^{B-j}\right)\\
> &\qquad\qquad-\frac{T}{z}\sum_{j=0}^{B-1}\binom{T-1}{j}z^{B-j}\tag{6.3}\\
> &=B\left(\sum_{j=0}^B\binom{T-1}{j}z^{B-j}+\frac{1}{z}\sum_{j=0}^{B-1}\binom{T-1}{j}z^{B-j}\right)\\
> &\qquad\qquad-\frac{T}{z}\sum_{j=0}^{B-1}\binom{T-1}{j}z^{B-j}\tag{6.4}\\
> &=B\binom{T-1}{B}+\left(B-(T-B)\frac{1}{z}\right)\sum_{j=0}^{B-1}\binom{T-1}{j}z^{B-j}\tag{6.5}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=B\binom{T-1}{B}}
> \end{align*}
> and the claim (5) follows.

*Comment:*

- In (6.1) we change the order of summation $j\to B-j$.
- In (6.2) we use the binomial identity $\binom{p}{q}=\frac{p}{q}\binom{p-1}{q-1}$.
- In (6.3) we use $\binom{p}{q}=\binom{p-1}{q}+\binom{p-1}{q-1}$.
- In (6.4) we shift the index of the middle sum by starting with $j=0$.
- In (6.5) we observe the factor in front of the sum is zero. :-)
  \begin{align*}
  B-(T-B)\frac{1}{z}&=B-(T-B)\left(\frac{T}{B}-1\right)^{-1}\\
  &=B-(T-B)\frac{B}{T-B}=0
  \end{align*}

Comment: This looks amazing! Thanks a lot! Could you give me some tutorial about coefficient of operator? I'd like to know the operation rules of it.

Comment: @Bryan: You're welcome. The hints given *[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2635408/annihilated-coefficient-extractor-ace/2636184#2636184)* provide some information about the *coefficient of* operator.